# JSF : Variable not accessible in ValueExpression : Wrong FaceletContext and no access to UIComponent’s VariableMapper

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have an application with complex validations which I can only perform based on the model hierarchy, so I can not use JSF’s validation stage.

My problem is that I need to link back the validation errors to the gui (visually show the textfields that need attention). So I need to link UI Components with domain model items somewhere.

I was hoping to realise this using a PreRenderComponentEventListener :

- my validatorcomponent stores Constraintvalidations where I have access to the object and property that needs attention.
- I use the ValueExpression of the UIComponent to retrieve the correct object the Component binds to.

At first this seemed to work : 
I have the following in a xhtml page :

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/mainTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">  
   <ui:repeat value="#{contactController.contactManager.contactList}" var="contact">
          <h:inputText value="#{contact.name}"/>
          <h:inputText value="#{contact.firstName}"/>
          <br/>
      </ui:repeat>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Now assume I have a list of contacts where one firstName fails.

ValueExpression’s expressionstring gives me “#{contact.firstName}” : I build a new ValueExpression from this one to retrieve the parent “#{contact}” and can check if the failing firstname is the one of the correct contact in the list.

So I do something like this in the Listener :

```
private Object extractParent(UIInput input) {
   FaceletContext faceletElContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
   ValueExpression orig = input.getValueExpression("value");
   String parent = getParent(orig.getExpressionString());
   ValueExpression valueExpression = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(faceletElContext,"#{"+parent+"}", Object.class);
   return valueExpression.getValue(faceletElContext);
}
```

Now this only works when the repeat is in the top facelet. 

As soon As my complex app uses include files and  or  this start to fail this because of 2 reasons :

- The facelet context is the wrong one, not the one of the nested xhtml and thus it does not have the variable in it’s variableMapper
- The variable is defined in the UIComponent’s valueexpression itself but that one is not accessible, has private access only so I can not use that one either.

So I am completely stuck ! Can someone provide me an alternative please ?

**UPDATE after evaluation of response from @BalusC** :
I tried with the `ELContext` but without success. I investigated a bit further and the core problem is that neither `ELContext` nor `FaceletContext` allows me access to variables defined in include files :

- the `ELContext` does not have them
- the `FaceletContext` seems to be the one of the last include file all the time and thus not the correct one.

I have a small testcase which proves this : When rendering the "contactinner" inputtext the ELContext has not this variable and the faceletcontext has the wrong xhtml hierarchy.

All help very very much appreciated.

test.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition>
<h:form id="myform">
    <c:set var="itemContact" value="#{contactController.contact}"/>
    <c:set var="itemPerson" value="#{contactController.person}"/>
    <ui:include src="contact.xhtml"/>
    <ui:include src="person.xhtml"/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{contactController.process}"/>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

contact.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition>
     <c:set var="contactinner" value="#{itemContact}"/>
     <h:inputText value="#{contactinner}"/>
</ui:composition>
```

person.xhtml :

```
<ui:composition>
    <c:set var="personinner" value="#{itemPerson}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{personinner}"/>
</ui:composition>
```

faces-config.xml (extract) :

```
<system-event-listener>
<system-event-listener-class>TestSystemEventListener</system-event-listener-class>
<system-event-class>javax.faces.event.PreRenderComponentEvent</system-event-class>
</system-event-listener>
```

TestSystemEventListener (extract) :

```
public class TestSystemEventListener implements SystemEventListener {
    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
       UIInput input = (UIInput) event.getSource();
       FaceletContext faceletElContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       ValueExpression orig = input.getValueExpression("value");
}
```

Running this, when the evenlistener is launched for the inputext in the first xhtml `#{contactInner}` I get teh following data in the listener :

```
orig = {com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression@24201}"/xhtml/contact.xhtml @6,43 value=\"#{contactinner}\""
    orig = {com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl@24220}"ValueExpression[#{contactinner}]"
    expr = {java.lang.String@24270}"#{contactinner}"
    varMapper = {com.sun.el.lang.VariableMapperImpl@24271}
    vars = {java.util.HashMap@24275} size = 1
       [0] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@24278}"contactinner" -> "/xhtml/contact.xhtml @5,54 value=\"#{itemContact}\""


context = {com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@24200}
    elContext = {com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl@24205}
    functionMapper = {com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler@24284}
    variableMapper = {com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl$VariableMapperImpl@24221}
        variables = {java.util.HashMap@24289} size = 2
        [0] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@24292}"itemContact" -> "/xhtml/test.xhtml @9,68 value=\"#{contactController.contact}\""
        [1] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@24295}"itemPerson" -> "/xhtml/test.xhtml @10,66 value=\"#{contactController.person}\""           

faceletElContext = {com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext@24199}
    faces = {com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@24200}
    ctx = {com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl@24205}
    facelet = {com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet@24151}"/xhtml/person.xhtml"
    faceletHierarchy = {java.util.ArrayList@24206} size = 2
    [0] = {com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet@23792}"/xhtml/test.xhtml"
    [1] = {com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet@24151}"/xhtml/person.xhtml"
    varMapper = {com.sun.faces.facelets.el.VariableMapperWrapper@24207}
    target = {com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl$VariableMapperImpl@24221}
    vars = {java.util.HashMap@24222} size = 1
        [0] = {java.util.HashMap$Entry@24225}"personinner" -> "/xhtml/person.xhtml @5,52 value=\"#{itemPerson}\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ELContext` instance as obtained by [`FacesContext#getELContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getELContext%28%29), not the `FaceletContext`.

```
private Object extractParent(UIInput input) {
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    ValueExpression orig = input.getValueExpression("value");
    String parent = getParent(orig.getExpressionString());
    ValueExpression valueExpression = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(elContext, "#{" + parent + "}", Object.class);
    return valueExpression.getValue(elContext);
}
```

A shorthand is by the way [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).

```
private Object extractParent(UIInput input) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ValueExpression orig = input.getValueExpression("value");
    String parent = getParent(orig.getExpressionString());
    return context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + parent + "}", Object.class);
}
```

Comment: Hi,  I tried this approach but is does not seem to work either.  I made a small testcase which isolates the problem and added it to the description.

Comment: Mojarra 2.0.3, no I have not tried the latest one since I'm bound to it by the project here and the app server, I'll give it a try if I can plugin another one

Comment: I tried with 2.0.9 and 2.1.8 and have exactly the same behaviour.